# How does pandas get_dummies convert values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this column

`df["Pclass"].tail()`

```
Pclass

2
1
3
1
3
```

I created dummies of the column

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df["Pclass"],prefix="Pclass")
df = pd.concat([df,dummies],axis=1)
```

result

```
df["Pclass_1"].tail()


    Pclass_1    Pclass_2    Pclass_3
886   0             1         0
887   1             0         0
888   0             0         1
889   1             0         0
890   0             0         1
```

I don't quite get it. After which rules the numbers in the column are transformed into the 1s and 0s.

Comment: more like a pivot the columns become the value of each row

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)

It basically pivots each unique value of the category's to it's own column and has a boolean flag (`1` or `0`) to flag which categorical value was present on that row.

Let's look at a less abstract example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sex':['male', 'female', 'unknown', 'female']})

       sex
0     male
1   female
2  unknown
3   female

df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['sex'], prefix='sex'))

       sex  sex_female  sex_male  sex_unknown
0     male           0         1            0
1   female           1         0            0
2  unknown           0         0            1
3   female           1         0            0
```

As you can see, first row in our original column is `male` and in our dummies column `sex_male` we see that there's a flag `1`.

```
       sex  sex_female  sex_male  sex_unknown
0     male           0         1            0
```

Then on the second row, in our original column the value is `female` and we see in our dummies column `sex_female` has flag `1`:

```
       sex  sex_female  sex_male  sex_unknown
1   female           1         0            0
```

And so on.

What's also important to remember is that when you apply `pd.get_dummies`:

> `amount of new dummie columns  = amount of unique values in original caterogical column`

---

In machine learning terms, we call this **one-hot encoding**

With [`scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) it would look as followed:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder()
encoder.fit_transform(df['sex'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)).toarray()

array([[0., 1., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Predictive models that depend on numeric inputs cannot directly
handle open text fields or categorical attributes.
Instead, these information-rich data need to be processed prior to
presenting the information to a model.
Tree-based and Naive Bayes models are exceptions; most models
require that the predictors take numeric form.

**Creating Dummy Variables for Unordered Categories is an approach for transforming categorical attributes to numerical.** @Erfan has answered what dummy variables do. But take the case of encoding ordered attributes: An unordered predictor with C categories can be represented by C−1
binary dummy variables or a hashed version of binary dummy variables.
These methods effectively present the categorical information to the
models.

But now suppose that the C categories have a relative ordering. For
example, consider a predictor that has the categories of “low”, “medium”,
and “high.”
**Creating dummy attributes as done for Unordered Data would miss the
information contained in the relative ordering.**

For ordered data encoding:

- Polynomial Contrast: A contrast is a linear combination of variables
  (parameters or statistics) whose coefficients add up to zero, allowing
  comparison of different treatments.
- Treat the predictors as unordered factors. If the true underlying pattern
  is linear or quadratic, unordered dummy variables may not effectively
  uncover this trend.
- Translate the ordered categories into a single set of numeric scores
  based on context-specific information.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a dummy column for each value that appeared in the original column, and then for each row puts a 1 if that row had the value corresponding to the dummy column and a 0 otherwise.

The row 886 had a 2 in column Pclass, so that is converted to a 1 in column Pclass_2 and a 0 in all other dummy columns.

Row 887 had a 1 in column Pclass, so that is converted to a 1 in column Pclass_1and a 0 in all other dummy columns.